# cannot convert parameter from 'PCHAR' to 'LPCWSTR'

Tags: windows, api, winapi

- I have defined the pointer size_Drive as  :

  ```
  PCHAR size_Drive ;
  ```

  then i used the function lstrlen  :

  ```
  size_Drive += (lstrlen(size_Drive) + 1) ;  (line 28)
  ```

  but it gives me the following ERROR :

  ```
  1>c:\users\hp.hp-pc\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\getvolumeinfo\getvolumeinfo\getvolumeinfo.cpp(28) : error C2664: 'lstrlenW' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'PCHAR' to 'LPCWSTR'
  1>        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
  ```

Answer (score 1):

`PCHAR` is a typedef for `char` whereas `LPCWSTR` is a typedef for `const wchar_t*`, and in a Unicode build `lstrlen` is a macro for the Unicode function `lstrlenW`.

You should call `lstrlenA` specifically to use the ANSI function.

Comment: Or change `PCHAR` to `TCHAR*` or `LPTSTR` so that it always matches what `lstrlen()` expects regardless of whether Ansi vs Unicode is being used.